# Equalizer (EQ) for all sound in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, audio

Looking for a Windows (using Windows 7 specifically) equalizer program.  Not sure how sound is setup in windows so I don't know if it would be a single EQ or different EQ depending on the source or output.

Specifically I have a pair of bluetooth headphones that have too much bass and I'd like to just turn it down permanently (at least for the headphones, ideally if I'm using speakers those could have separate EQ settings).

Preferably free/open source but open to commercial if it's really standout.

Comment: I found [Equalizer APO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/) although unfortunately it's hosted at sourceforge which I was under the impression had some questionable spyware issues.