# Equalizer for system volume in Windows 10

Tags: audio, windows-10

I would like an equalizer for the system sound on Windows 10.

The problem I am trying to solve is, I am working regularly with some coworkers who work in another office, so we meet over VoiP. For whatever reason, some of these meetings have a very high-pitched noise, like my ears are ringing. I'd like to remove this noise. I have experience producing computer music, so I know enough to take an equalizer and cut the frequencies that the noise is on.

I'd prefer a free-as-in-beer solution, but as long as the software is reputable, I'm not picky about free-as-in-freedom or open-source software.

---

My request is a near-duplicate of [Equalizer (EQ) for all sound in Windows?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26981/equalizer-eq-for-all-sound-in-windows), but that question is about Windows 7, not Windows 10.

Comment: Have you try another VoIP system, this IMHO is a better way to resolve your problem.

Comment: Windows 7 vs 10 does not make a difference here IMO. EqualizerApo suggested in a comment to that question is a solid option.